# Graphviz dot-file crazy edge positioning

Tags: graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I have a problem with the positions of the edges in my dot-file. [image]

In the dot-file I used contrainsts=false to exclude the edges m and l from the ranking and gave it some headport and tailport (with pygraphviz: `headport='e', tailport='e'`. 
They got a crazy shape. I want to have them on the right side of the nodes.

This is the dot-file:

```
strict digraph "" {
graph [bb="0,0,717.03,767.02",
    edges="{'arrowsize': '4.0'}",
    rankdir=LR,
    size="100,100",
];
cen0
   [height=0.5,
    label=a,
    rank=0,
    ];
3    [
    label=b,
    rank=1,
    ];
cen0 -> 3
   [label=z,
    pos=e];
0
   [label=c,
    rank=1,
    ];
cen0 -> 0
   [label=z,
    pos=e];
cor22
   [label=d,
    rank=2,
    ];
3 -> cor22
   [label=2,
    pos=e];
con23
   [label=e,
    rank=2,
    ];
3 -> con23
   [label=1,
    ];
cor2
   [label=g,
    rank=2,
    ];
0 -> cor2
   [label=4];
con4
   [label=h,
    rank=2,
    ];
0 -> con4
   [label=3];
1
   [label="Why I can't delete the attribute 'width' 
from this node?:
   Warning: Unable to reclaim box space in spline 
routing for edge \"con4\" ->\"con23\". Something is 
probably seriously wrong.
",
    rank=2,
    width=2.5731];
0 -> 1
   [label=k];
cor2:e -> cor22:e
   [constraint=false,
   rank=3
    label=l];
con4:e -> con23:e
   [constraint=false,
    rank=3
    label="Why this way?"];
}
```

I also wondered about why there comes that warning, when I delete the one last "width"-attribute. 
How could I get my edges in the way, I expected?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an automatically generated product with a lot of "noise" - I have taken the liberty to almost completely re-write the code, to make it easier for me to work and test, and to concentrate on the essentials. You will add what is important for you back in and find out whether or not some of that breaks it.

With a good amount of trial and error, I found four major changes necessary:

- The four third level nodes need to be in the same rank (`rank = 3` does not help)
- They need to be connected in the desired order by invisible edges
- The edges between these nodes need to maintain the right hierarchical level, with the arrow pointing backwards
- `xlabels` rather than `labels` need to be used for the edges

So here my largely edited code

```
digraph so 
{
    rankdir = LR;
    // edge[ arrowsize = 4 ];           // you don't want that

    cen0[ label = "a" ];
    3   [ label = "b" ];
    0   [ label = "c" ];
    cen0 -> { 3 0 }[ label = "z" ];

    cor22[ label = "d" ];
    con23[ label = "e" ];
    3 -> cor22[ label = "2" ];
    3 -> con23[ label = "1" ];

    cor2[ label = "g" ];
    con4[ label = "h" ];
    1   [ label = "Why I can't delete the attribute 'width' from this node?:\nWarning: Unable to reclaim box space in spline routing for edge \"con4\" ->\"con23\".\nSomething is probably seriously wrong.\n---  Width attribute not present here!  ---" ];
    0 -> cor2[ label = "4"];
    0 -> con4[ label = "3" ];
    0 -> 1[ label = "k" ];

    {rank = same; cor22 con23 cor2 con4 1 }
    cor22 -> con23 -> cor2 -> con4[ style = invis ]
    cor22:e -> cor2:e[ dir = back, xlabel = "   l" ];
    con23:e -> con4:e[ dir = back, xlabel = "   Is this better?" ];
}
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I found out that 'special' attribute. `splines=curved` gives them that defined shape.

Comment: That's quite strange - I get `Warning: edge labels with splines=curved not supported in dot - use xlabels` and a very garbled graph by adding `splines = curved`. If it works for you, problem solved, though!  --  As a matter of interest, what OS and which graphviz version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, it's solved by this. But for me it makes some sense, that the kind of the line should be determined. I use graphviz version 2.40.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

Comment: By the way, that warning I get too, but it's ok, changing the labels to x labels doesn't matter for my case.

Answer (score 1):

The missing attribute is `splines=curved`, added to my graphviz code gives:
[image]